# Using Magellan Meridian and QGIS GPS Tools

Tags: qgis, gps, gpx

I am using QGIS 2.0.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.  I have a Magellan Meridian GPS and I trying to use the GPS Tools plugin to download waypoints to a layer in QGIS.  I have successfully used the Gebabbel interface with GPSBabel to extract waypoints from the GPS to a .gpx file.

The only way I have successfully used the GPS Tools to download waypoints and add to a layer is by using the following command in the GPS device editor.  This is the same command that Gebabbel issues.

```
gpsbabel -w -i magellan,baud=9600 -o gpx -f /dev/ttyS0 -F /home/robert/GPSpoints/waypoints.gpx
```

I also use “waypoints” for the Layer name and Output file text boxes on the main GPS Tools dialog window.

This method seems to only work once.  If I remove the layer from QGIS, delete the .gpx file, and repeat the download request in the GPS Tools, I get an error message or QGIS becomes unresponsive,

I know the Meridian is an old unit, but is anyone successfully using it with QGIS GPS Tools.

Comment: Please include a screenshot of the error message you are receiving in QGIS.

Comment: I do not understand how to add a screenshot but the message is "The layer waypoints.gpx?type=waypoint is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map" or QGIS just freezes.